# resizeable textarea

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got such definition of textareaBox and textarea in CSS file:

```
.textareaBox {
   border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
   width: 371px;
   height: 73px;
   float: right;
   padding: 5px 10px;
}
.textareaBox textarea {
   width: 370px;
   height: 67px;
   line-height: 18px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #888888;
   font-family: "Segoe UI Light", segoeuil;
```

}

On ASPX page I've placed

```
<asp:Content ID=....>
<link type="text/css" href="~/stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".textareaBox").resizable();
    });
</script>
```

But textareaBox doesn't change its size. And textarea inside it always when it becomes bigger than textareaBox outside of the textareaBox.

```
<div class="textareaBox">
 <textarea ... rows="10" cols="10" class="textarea jq_black"></textarea>
</div>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: are you calling $(".textareaBox").resizable() before <div class="textareaBox"> has finished loading?

Comment: is $(".textareaBox").resizable() placed above your div on the ascx file?

Comment: yes it is.(actually it is aspx file)

Comment: move it after your div or replace your code with $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".textareaBox").resizable();
});

Comment: doesn't work any of this

Answer (score 1):

Are you referencing the "resize" image somewhere in your "stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" stylesheet? If not, add a reference to this stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: it's difficult to tell without seeing everything...  try setting .textareaBox textarea  to margin:0; padding:0;